# How to pass multiple data to view in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Im passing some datas to my blade view with
`return view('show')->with('nomeutente', $nomeutente);` previously withdrawn with a request.

As long as it is a single value, everything is ok, but if you add values, I don't understand how to do it.

Example:         
                  `return view('show')->with('nomeutente', $nomeutente);
                  return view('show')->with('password', $password);`

in my Controller-> DataController.php

```php
    public function create(){
        return view('create');
    }
    public function show(Request $r){
        $nomeutente = $r->nomeutente;
        $password = $r->password;

        return view('show')->with('nomeutente', $nomeutente);
        return view('show')->with('password', $password);
    }
```

in my Create Page-> create.blade.php

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nomeutente">Nome Utente</label>
                <input name="nomeutente" id="nomeutente" class="form-control" placeholder="Inserisci il nome utente (nome.cognome)"/>
                <br>
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control"/>
            </div>
```

in my Show Page-> show.blade.php

`<div>
    <h1>Il tuo nome utente:  {{ $nomeutente }}</h1>
    <h1>La tua password è:  {{ $password }}</h1>
</div>`

Error image: [Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAcIO.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `compact` to return variables to the view.

```
return view('show',compact('nomeutente','password'));
```

View will be the same

```
<div>
    <h1>Il tuo nome utente:  {{ $nomeutente }}</h1>
    <h1>La tua password è:  {{ $password }}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: What if I wanted to collect the results of a checkbox or radio button?

Comment: @AndreaLeto Mention all those permutations and combinations in question to get a complete answer instead of thinking requirements on the fly.

Comment: you can get them as well. `$selected = $r->checkbox_name;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [compact](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) to achieve the same.

```
return view('show', compact(['nomeutente', 'password']));
```